# importing multiple cache files in Maya using Python

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to write a script for importing multiple cache files for a model in Maya using Python. So far I have got the following:

```
import  maya.cmds as cmds
cache_files_path = 'D:/Project/sfin/work/data/ram/geo'

latest_look_file = 'D:/Project/chars/ram/look/maya/ram_clean_look_v002_t005.mb'

# open the latest look file
cmds.file(latest_look_file, f = True, op = "v=0;", typ = 'mayaBinary', o = True)

cmds.select(all = True)
```

Now I need to start importing existing geometry cache from the 'cache_files_path' to the respective objects. Maya2013 has the mel script 'doImportCacheFile.mel' which does the task I guess. But I couldn't proceed from here.

Comment: does the path contain multi-object cache files?

Comment: @ hus787 yes inside the path contains the folders for different objects which in turn has cache files inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the file that you have opened has a `mesh` named `"foo_mesh"`, which can be checked using `isinstance(pc.PyNode("foo_mesh"), pc.nt.Mesh`. And there is a cache file for it  named `"foo_mesh_cache.xml"` (consider this as the cache metadata) and `"foo_mesh_data.mc"`

To apply this cache to the mesh something like the following should work:

```
import pymel.core as pc

mesh = "foo_mesh"
xml = "foo_mesh_cache.xml"
data = "foo_mesh_data.mc"

pc.mel.doImportCacheFile(xml, "", [mesh], list())
```

And to find out whether a cache file has already been applied to a mesh, list it's history and see if it contains node of type `pc.nt.CacheFile`.

Comment: could you please explain the last line? and can it be done using maya commands instead of pymel?? why is list() used?? thanks

Comment: what about using cmds.cacheFile()?

Comment: A cache file can contain point cache of multiple objects and that info is  held under channel name (*read the xml file*). So if a cache contained multiple channel you'd have to tell which one to be applied on which mesh in case multiple were provided. But since you said, in the comment under the question, that the caches are per-object therefore the list is left empty (take all that with a grain of salt and read the code file which contains the command at `whatis doImportCacheFile`). Seems like your pymel isn't fixed yet, failback to `cmd.eval` and supply it as mel string.

Comment: I couldn't fix pymel for eclipse but it works in maya so i can use it in my code. I was just trying to find another solution like using cmds.cacheFile(). I don't know mel so didn't bother much about reading the code, thought calling the mel script should do the job. I would go through the script. I am still getting error while using the above command you mentioned. Maybe I haven't given the right arguments when calling mel script. I would get back if I can't fix it. Thank you.