# Load a cache file in Maya using Python and create the same render output

Tags: python, maya

I try to load a cache file in Maya using a python script. I used the code snipped posted here: [importing multiple cache files in Maya using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174424/importing-multiple-cache-files-in-maya-using-python?answertab=active#tab-top)

My code looks like this:

```
pm.mel.doImportCacheFile(myCachePath, "", [selectedObject], list())
```

`myCachePath`: Stores the path to the xml file
`selectedObject`: e.g. `flameShepe1` (represents the fluid container)

First I thought that it finally worked, but whenever I press the play button and render an image again I don't get the same output. The simulation has the same shape but the colors are not the same.

When I use `Fluid nCache -> Attache Existing` ... everything works.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the attach cache command, Attaching cache to fluid is different, try :

```
pm.mel.doImportFluidCacheFile(pathCache, "xmlcache", ['fluid1'], [])
```

Hope it will do the trick !

---EDIT---

Note that you could do without pymel formating a string like this :

```
lineToEval = 'doImportFluidCacheFile("{0}", "xmlcache", {{"{1}"}}, {{}});'.format( pathCache, fluidsSel[0])
mel.eval(lineToEval)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was exacty what I was looking for. There is one last thing I am truggeling with. I can apply the xml file to "flame" or to "flameShape". Both works. In your answer you recommended fluidsSel[0]. For me that looks like an array. How can I get that? Thanks!

Comment: in my second example, i format the Mel command with python. array in Mel are : var = {"one", "two", "three"}. If you multiple fluids in an array, you could make insert multiple name ",".join(fluidsSel). In my example fluidSel[0] = 'fluid1'